# Why is my gated check in failing to run the final check in task?

Tags: azure-devops, gated-checkin

I am having difficulties with the last two projects I have created using gated check-ins in Azure DevOps.

The error I receive:

`[Error]The shelveset [ommitted] could not be found for check-in`

We are using an onpremises agent and the last two projects I have created get this error on the gated check-in. However, our older apps that have identical build pipelines seem to be working fine so I do not understand why this is happening.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is the azure devops version you are using? The gated check-ins looks like build policy in Build validation for azure devops 2019

Comment: 2019,whats weird is that its working fine for our other projects. Just not for any new ones.

Comment: I cannot reproduce above error. Could update your original question with detailed steps(with screenshots) to reproduce this error.

Comment: Yes each pipeline has 3 steps, nuget install, restore then vs build. The issue occurs also on a 3rd npm build pipeline. The error does not occur in any tasks within the build pipeline, just the final 'check in gated changes' task which is generated if the gated check in trigger is enabled and someone has attempted to check in. I will try to update the question with some more information.

Comment: Is your azure devops 2019 server on premise or cloud based?

Comment: Cloud based, using on premises agents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same issue on my on premise agent as well as hosted agents. After investigating it seems like the account conflicts cause this error, that the build agent trys to check in the shelvesets with build service account other than you own account.

The same issue has been submitted to Microsoft. You can vote it up and keep track on it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/812664/gated-check-in-error-could-not-found-the-shelveset.html), or your can submit a new issue regarding this issue on the same site by clicking on "**Report a problem**".